# pass stdout as file name for command line util?

Tags: linux, bash, file-io, stdout, pipe

I'm working with a command line utility that requires passing the name of a file to write output to, e.g.

```
foo -o output.txt
```

The only thing it writes to `stdout` is a message that indicates that it ran successfully.  I'd like to be able to pipe everything that is written to `output.txt` to another command line utility.  My motivation is that output.txt will end up being a 40 GB file that I don't need to keep, and I'd rather pipe the streams than work on massive files in a stepwise manner.

Is there any way in this scenario to pipe the real output (i.e. `output.txt`) to another command?  Can I somehow magically pass `stdout` as the file argument?

Comment: some versions of unix/linux have access to stdout/err via `/dev/stdout`, etc.

Comment: the usual "write to stdout" convention for unixy tools is to use `-` as a filename (i.e. `foo -o -`). In your code, you could simply detect that special filename and use `stdout` for output instead of an `fopen`ed file. Don't print a status in that case, or print it to `stderr` which you can redirect separately.

Comment: All excellent suggestions with great insights into the different aspects of the problem.  I think the named pipe is the way to go, but the two answers are essentially dupes -- which do I mark as the answer?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

### Solution 1: Using [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution)

The most convenient way of doing this is by using process substitution. In bash the syntax looks as follows:

```
foo -o >(other_command)
```

(Note that this is a [bashism](https://askubuntu.com/q/1059265/18623). There's similar solutions for other shells, but bottom line is that it's not portable.)

### Solution 2: Using [named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) explicitly

You can do the above explicitly / manually as follows:

1. Create a named pipe using the `mkfifo` command.

   ```
   mkfifo my_buf
   ```
2. Launch your other command with that file as input

   ```
   other_command < my_buf
   ```
3. Execute `foo` and let it write it's output to `my_buf`

   ```
   foo -o my_buf
   ```

### Solution 3: Using `/dev/stdout`

You can also use the device file `/dev/stdout` as follows

```
foo -o /dev/stdout | other_command
```

Answer (score 53):

Named pipes work fine, but you have a nicer, more direct syntax available via bash process substitution that has the added benefit of not using a permanent named pipe that must later be deleted (process substitution uses temporary named pipes behind the scenes):

`foo -o >(other command)`

Also, should you want to pipe the output to your command and also save the output to a file, you can do this:

`foo -o >(tee output.txt) | other command`

Answer (score 49):

For the sake of making stackoverflow happy let me write a long enough sentence because my proposed solution is only 18 characters long instead of the required 30+

```
foo -o /dev/stdout
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it *also* captures the command's normal stdout, and if it is both emitting unwanted stdout *and* writing a wanted file, then the result will contain the unwanted content as well.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the magic of UNIX and create a named pipe :)

1. Create the pipe

   ```
   $ mknod -p mypipe
   ```
2. Start the process that reads from the pipe

   ```
   $ second-process < mypipe
   ```
3. Start the process, that writes into the pipe

   ```
   $ foo -o mypipe
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I use /dev/tty as the output filename, equivalent to using /dev/nul/ when you want to output nothing at all.  Then | and you are done.

Comment: tty is not always available. Better use /dev/stdout

Answer (score 0):

`foo -o <(cat)`

if for some reason you don't have permission to write to `/dev/stdout`