# Redirect output file to stdout

Tags: bash, stdout, io-redirection, qsub, sungridengine

In `qsub` Oracle Grid Engine, this redirects the output to a file `out.txt`,

```
qsub -o $(pwd)/out.txt -sync y awesome_script.sh
```

How to redirect the output to `stdout` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `/dev/stdout` as the filename.

```
qsub -o /dev/stdout -sync y awesome_script.sh
```

More info can be found in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36403

---

Edit:

A common Unix idiom is that the filename `-` means stdin for an input
file and stdout for an output file. This has to be explicitly handled by
the program, though; it's not automatic. I can't find anything saying
whether `qsub` uses this idiom. Try it, it might work.

If you want to pipe the output to another command that does something
with it, you could create a named pipe (`man mkfifo`) and send the
output to that, with the other process reading from the pipe. Start the
read process first.

For another idea, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7757228),
which explains how to use bash process substitution. I haven't used this
much, but I think it would be something like:

```
qsub -o >(other-command-or-pipeline) -sync y awesome_script.sh
```

If you simply want to see the output in real-time, you could specify
`/dev/tty` as the file. Or, you could output to a file and watch it with
`tail -f`.

Hope one of these ideas works for you.

Comment: Many Thanks for your response. It seems this approach does not function with `qsub` though.

Comment: @elm: How is it failing? Is `/dev/stdout` not there? How about `/dev/fd`? What OS?

Comment: Program somehow stalls, no cpu loads, no I/O, no files transformed. Using Centos 6. May the issue be at redirecting remote `/dev/stdout` to master `/dev/stdout` ?

Comment: Any help appreciated. +1 for devising proposed solution which works in most cases.

Comment: Hi @elm, looks like some of that was useful. Since other people may encounter a similar problem, please consider editing your question or leaving a comment, to let them know which approach worked best for you.

Comment: Best approach that did work for the use case included `tail -f`.