# Write to STDERR by filename even if not writable for the user

Tags: linux, bash

My user does not have write permissions for STDERR:

```
user@host:~> readlink -e /dev/stderr
/dev/pts/19
user@host:~> ls -l /dev/pts/19
crw--w---- 1 sysuser tty 136, 19 Apr 26 14:02 /dev/pts/19
```

It is generally not a big issue,

```
echo > /dev/stderr
```

fails with

```
-bash: /dev/stderr: Permission denied
```

but usual redirection like

```
echo >&2
```

works alright.

However I now need to cope with a 3rd-party binary which only provides logging output to a specified file:

```
./utility --log-file=output.log
```

I would like to see the logging output directly in STDERR.

I cannot do it the easy way like `--log-file=/dev/stderr` due to missing write permissions. On other systems where the write permissions are set this works alright.

Furthermore, I also need to parse output of the process to STDOUT, therefore I cannot simply send log to STDOUT and then redirect to STDERR with `>&2`. I tried to use the `script` utility (where the redirection to `/dev/stderr` works properly) but it merges STDOUT and STDERR together as well.

Comment: What is the shell's stderr connected to such that it works?

Comment: Why is your stderr such that you cannot write to it?  That's unusual — not impossible, but unusual.

Comment: Agreeing with Jonathan, I can `echo > /dev/stderr` all day

Comment: What is &2 pointing to?

Comment: Can you use `/dev/fd/2` as the file name instead?

Comment: @123: the notation `>&2` indicates that standard output should be sent to standard error; it isn't the name of a file per se.

Comment: @Jonathan - I have `/dev/stderr` -> `/proc/self/fd/2` -> `/dev/pts/19` and `/dev/fd/2` -> `/dev/pts/19`, so if it's the same for the asker, then that's no help.

Comment: Just replace stdout with stderr here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756609/pass-stdout-as-file-name-for-command-line-util-answer-use-named-pipes

Comment: @TobySpeight: that sounds plausible, which is one reason my suggestion wasn't an answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's a file descriptor, it points to a file otherwise known as /proc/self/fd/2.

Comment: @Mort: The option with named pipes was the one I originally went for but it has many problems: you cannot view the output real-time (unless you start a background `cat`) and you need to care for the cleanup afterwards. Too much complexity for such a small thing. Answer from @toby-speight does the same but in a very neat manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Bash process substitution:

```
./utility --log-file=>(cat>&2)
```

The substitution will appear to the utility like `--log-file=/dev/fd/63`, which can be opened.  The `cat` process inherits fd 2 without needing to open it, so it can do the forwarding.

I tested the above using `chmod -w /dev/stderr` and `dd if=/etc/issue of=/dev/stderr`.  That fails, but changing to `dd if=/etc/issue of=>(cat>&2)` succeeds.

Note that your error output may suffer more buffering than you would necessarily want/expect, and will not be synchronous with your shell prompt.  In other words, your prompt may appear mixed in with error output that arrives at your terminal after `utility` has completed.  The `dd` example will likely demonstrate this.  <s>You may want to append `;wait` after the command to ensure that the `cat` has finished before your `PS1` prompt appears: `./utility --log-file=>(cat>&2); wait`</s>