# Does any magic "stdout" file exists?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe

Some utilities can not output to stdout.

Example

```
util out.txt
```

It works. But sometimes I want to pipe the output to some other program like:

```
util out.txt | grep test
```

Does any magic "stdout" file in linux exists, so when I will replace the `out.txt` above, it will work redirect the data to `stdout` pipe?

Note: I know `util out.txt && cat out.txt | grep test`, so please do not post answers like this.

Comment: Does your utility comply with POSIX utility syntax guidelines? If so, it will recognize `-` to mean stdin or stdout, as appropriate for the position.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756609/pass-stdout-as-file-name-for-command-line-util-answer-use-named-pipes) is answered here.

Comment: *Why* your program doesn't natively support stdout, too, is important. As Basile says, some programs jump around in their output file while writing them, rather than doing a single front-to-back pass. In that case, streaming data directly to stdout without buffering it in a file beforehand is literally impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `/dev/stdout`. But that won't always work if a program needs to [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) (or [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)) it.

Usually `/dev/stdout` is a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/1` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)).

IIRC some version of some programs (probably [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html)) are handling *specifically* the `/dev/stdout` filename (e.g. to be able to work *without* `/proc/` being mounted).

A common, but not universal, convention for program arguments is to consider `-`, when used as a file name, to represent the stdout (or the stdin). For example, see [tar(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) used with `-f -`.

If you write some utility, I recommend following that `-` convention when possible  and document if *stdout* needs to be seekable.

Some programs are testing if *stdout* or *stdin* is a terminal (e.g. using [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)) to behave differently, e.g. by using [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). If you write such a program, I recommend providing a program option to disable that detection.