# Pass string as file to java keytool in bash terminal?

Tags: bash, keytool

I am trying to pass a base64 decoded string to java keytool (extracted from a kubernetes secret):

```
$ keytool -list -v -storepass mypass -keystore <<EOF
> "$(kubectl get secret trust-secret -o jsonpath='{.data.trust}' | base64 -d)"
> EOF
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
Command option -keystore needs an argument.
keytool -list [OPTION]...

Lists entries in a keystore

Options:

 -rfc                            output in RFC style
 -alias <alias>                  alias name of the entry to process
 -keystore <keystore>            keystore name
 -storepass <arg>                keystore password
 -storetype <storetype>          keystore type
 -providername <providername>    provider name
 -providerclass <providerclass>  provider class name
 -providerarg <arg>              provider argument
 -providerpath <pathlist>        provider classpath
 -v                              verbose output
 -protected                      password through protected mechanism

Use "keytool -help" for all available commands
```

Not sure if this is even possible or if I am just doing the EOF thing wrong.

It works fine if I write to file first but would like to skip that part if possible.

Comment: Does the keytool expects data from `stdin`? If it does, why not to use piping?

Comment: No I think it only accepts input from a file - thats why I thought it might be possible to cat/pipe a string as a file to keytool.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/7756689/14363412  helps in any way?

Comment: Did you try `-keystore /dev/stdin << EOF`?